# I can't figure out how to apply values

Tags: java, arrays, variables, object

If I am trying to apply two separate int values to a value entered inside of a string array, how will I go about that? I have tried many methods, is that even possible. For example, here is a simple bit of code that I tested in a separate project:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    Cards gaI = new Cards("Example 1", "Attack", 5, "Defense", 5);
    Cards abI = new Cards("Example 2", "Attack", 5, "Defense", 10);
    Cards aII = new Cards("Example 3", "Attack", 5, "Defense", 10);

    Cards [] cards = new Cards [3];

    cards [0] = gaI; //
    cards [1] = abI;
    cards [2] = aII;

    //for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        for (Cards c : cards){
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is set up two different arrays, or maybe just one with number values, and apply it to each Object above to give them their own set values. Will it make more sense just to work with each Object but instead of making them objects, just declare them as variables and then add all the additional data individually within the same class? Getting them to print in the proper format was the easy part. I want to be able to make the int values their permanent value for each card. Similar to a Yu-Gi-Oh card for example. I hope I am asking this properly.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question in a clearer way please?

Comment: What do you mean by "their own set values"?

Comment: I think I may be figuring it out. But to answer your questing, I was meaning I wanted to grab a value from a string array and two int values from two different int arrays, return the string with the int values. For example ("Name", 250, 250) and make the string keep the int's as permanent values but I was going on about it all wrong. Still haven't figured it out but I am on the right track.

Comment: thanks for clearing up the question. I've posted an answer that might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through multiple arrays at the same time using a simple loop

```
int[] intValues1 = ...;
int[] intValues2 = ...;
String[] stringValues = ...;
// if you are sure the arrays have the same length, this will work OK for you
for (int i = 0; i < intValues1.length; i++) {
    Card c = new Card(stringValues[i], intValues1[i], intValues2[i]);
    ...
}
```

If the arrays have different lengths, then you need to adjust your loop condition, or you may get IndexOutOfBounds exception, e.g. like this

```
for (...; i < intValues1.length && i < intValues2.length && i < stringValues.length; ...)
```

To make the values in `Card` *permanent*

```
class Card {
    final String stringVal;
    final int intVal1;
    final int intVal2;
    public Card(stringVal, intVal1, intVal2) {
        this.stringVal = stringVal;
        this.intVal1 = intVal1;
        this.intVal2 = intVal2;
    }
}
```

And obviously, define only getters for the class.

Comment: By far one of the best explanations yet. Thank you so much!